# pass client side javascript value to server side C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to pass the value of a variable created in java script in to the server side.

I'm using asp.net AJAX C#.

I was able to insert the value into an asp:Label by using:

```
document.getelementbyid("MyLabel").innerhtml = "data";
```

but once i try to get the value in the server side:

```
string NewLabel = MyLabel.Text;
```

it shows a null error.

does anyone know a way to pass the java script value to the server?

Thank you.

Comment: Use asp.net HiddenField instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another control to send the value on each post, for example:

- `HiddenField`
- Any `Input` control

Example:

### ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%: this.myHidden.ClientID %>").val("your new value");
    });
</script>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="myHidden" Value='' />
```

### ASPX Code behind

```
string myHiddenValue = this.myHidden.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a hidden field and set the variable value on hidden field like this

i assume that `Mylable` is hidden field

```
  var javascriptvariable='a';
  $('#MyLabel').val(javascriptvariable);
```

and on server side

```
   string NewLabel = MyLabel.Value;
```

I have used jquery for this /

Answer (score 0):

You can send the client value to the server side either by posting the data, ajax or passing it as a parameter in a query string. Without doing any of these, I very much doubt that the server would be able to see the values set on the client side.