# Get client-side value to server-side ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, server, client, hidden-field

I tried to pass a variable from the client side to server side using `HiddenField` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600766/pass-client-side-javascript-value-to-server-side-c-sharp) example.

What I have tried so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script type ="text/javascript"> 
         <script type ="text/javascript"> 
                function passValue() {
                    document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = "some stuff";
                }
                 window.onload = passValue;

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>    
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick ="passValue()"/>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the server side I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a, b;
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("The input value is: " + HiddenField1.Value.ToString());
                a = HiddenField1.Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("The input value is: " + HiddenField1.Value.ToString());
                b = HiddenField1.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

When my page opens I expect to see on it the message: "The input value is: some stuff". The message appears only if I press the button because only in this case the IsPostBack becomes true.
What should I do so get the message without pressing the button? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to set up a web service to post that value to. Research ASP.Net Web Api.

Comment: Then is no other way to do this?

Comment: Web services allow your backend to communicate with the rest of the world. So, no, there is no other (good, obvious...) way to do what you are asking.

Comment: "I have seen this example but I don't know if it's what I need." — That's an example using Node.js for the server side code. You can't use Node.js's server side code when you are using ASP.NET for your server side code (and you can't put Node.js's server side code in the middle of your client side code, which is what you are doing).

Comment: @Quentin you're right. I gave this link like an example. I thought is a similar way for ASP.NET.

Comment: @magn — Yes, but the code you put in your question shoves the server side JS into the middle of the client side JS.

Comment: It's a part from the <script> </script> which on the client side. I put them together to simplify the things.

Comment: @Quentin , I edited my question. Is there any hint you could give me? Thanks in advance!